# Soil texture area distribution from SSURGO using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, distribution, soil, ssurgo

I can download SSURGO data and get the spatial shapefile with MUKEY and tabular data. What I need is a parser that can generate soil texture area distribution within another overlay polygon layer using ArcGIS Pro.

For example, the SSURGO data and a polygon overlay are as this:

[image]

I would like to get a soil texture breakdown within the overlay polygon:

```
Soil Texture    %Target Area
Silt Loam       59.8
Loam            17.1
Bedrock         10.7
Silty Clay Loam 6.9
Sandy Loam      3.7
Clay            0.9
Clay Loam       0.5
Sand            0.1
Loamy Sand      0
Sandy Clay Loam 0
Sandy Clay      0
Silty Clay      0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  For polygon overlay I always think of the Union tool first.

Comment: I think the important first step is to get a summary of MUKEY - Soil Texture (well, primary), then next is perhaps use an intersection summary of some sort to get the final  table.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and/additional information which may make your question clearer to potential answerers. When I’m looking to summarize the first tool I think about is the Summary Statistics tool.